# Xcode build & run error: "Process launch failed: Failed to get the task for process 216"

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, provisioning-profile, app-store-distribution-profile

After updating to Mavericks and making sure I got the latest updates of Xcode installed as well, Xcode suddenly fails to launch apps on the device.

It installs the app on my iPhone but then before running it, throws this error:

> Process launch failed: Failed to get the task for process 216

This is how the Code Signing settings look like since the update:

[image]

Also checked Scheme and it runs in Debug configuration.

Is this a known issue with Mavericks? How to fix it?

Comment: This Q/A worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806538/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk-ios-10-0-stic

Answer (score 71):

I got this error when signing it with a distribution profile. In my case, it was an Ad Hoc profile.

It was confusing to me because you can't 'run' and install the app directly to your device if you sign it with a distribution profile. For my case, I use testflightapp and was able to upload the IPA.

The error message is not very descriptive of the problem.

Also, if you are stuck, make sure you check the profiles for both the 'Project' and the 'Target'

Comment: This worked for me. obviously we cannot use the distribution profile anymore to test on devices unless it goes through test flight which is a hassle now...

Comment: I was getting the same error with different error codes but figured out that the issue was with my 'code signing identity'. I was using iOS distribution profile, changing it to developer profile solved my problem.

Answer (score 18):

Figured it out. My Developer Certificate was marked as "Expired" in Keychain (search Spotlight for "Keychain", then click on the "user" tab on the left). I deleted it, then went to Xcode > Preferences > Accounts, selected my ID and clicked on "View Details", then clicked the Update icon at the bottom left. Xcode re-installed the renewed certificate. Then I went to Build Settings and manually set the Debug configuration to use the Developer certificate Xcode just reinstalled for me.

Comment: Thanks. in my case I had the old certificates and the new renewed certificates (with the same name) in the keychain. When I deleted the old certificates, it worked!

Answer (score 10):

I think you use the distribution profile, you can revise like this:

[[image]]

Comment: Though you do not have reuptation to comments on question, it is not a good way to represent. Better wait until you have proper reputation to comment

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to go to Keychain, lock/unlock or unlock/lock Login, there is something with the signing that looses state.