# Inability to develop app because ' application could not be found on device' in iOS 13.0/Xcode 11 beta 5

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11, ios13

I am trying to build a new version of an app I am developing that has a previous version on the App Store. I have installed the iOS 13.0 developer beta and Xcode 11.0 beta 5 (11M382q) today, and suddenly I am having issues building my app on my iPhone.

Attempting to install the new version of an app that I have released onto the App Store did not change the app, it is still the latest official release, even though Xcode made the app open on my phone. If I build the app on a simulator my changes are present. I decided to delete the app off of my phone, now it will not reinstall the app, giving the error message `Install claimed to have succeeded, but application could not be found on device. bundleid = (my bundle id)`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241579/install-claimed-to-have-succeeded-but-application-could-not-be-found-on-device) question seems to have the same problem as me but no answers fix my issue.  I thought it may have to do with the iPhone Distribution/Development certificate I hold not being valid, yet building a different Xcode project works exactly as expected, with the app showing new features.

I don't know much about how Apple manages things like their Certificates, so if you need more information to diagnose my problem please do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: We've received a number of reports about this as radars over the past month.  None of the reports contained a sysdiagnose from the host nor device.  I've sent them all back to get data from originators, but so far, nobody has provided actionable data to investigate the bug.  Can you please file a radar (use Feedback Assistant or goto http://bugreport.apple.com) and include a sysdiagnose from both the device and host mac?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may seem a bit convoluted, but I simply deleted `Info.plist` file and manually re-added everything necessary into the file. Somehow upgrading from Xcode 10 to Xcode 11 beta 5 meant that the file was no longer 'corrupted'.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the problem was that I had downtime on Screen Time enabled. If you reinstall the app with downtime disabled and then add the app to "allowed apps" then it should work from then on.

Comment: I've done that, but now I'm getting `Internal launch error: process launch failed: failed to get the task for process 1277`. I hope this is some issue with the beta and I have not somehow messed up my app lol

But your method did make progress, so thanks!