# macOS 10.15 Beta: Install claimed to have succeeded, but application could not be found on device. bundleId =

Tags: ionic-framework, xcode11, macos-catalina

i got a problem with running a ios-app, developed with ionic 3 on MacOs 10.15 Beta (Catalina).

When i try to start the app with my real device (ios 13 Beta) i am getting the following error:

> "Install claimed to have succeeded, but application could not be found on device. bundleId ="

It is running on simulator...

Did anybody face the same issue?

I tried solutions from this thread:
[Install claimed to have succeeded, but application could not be found on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241579/install-claimed-to-have-succeeded-but-application-could-not-be-found-on-device)

Answer (score 1):

solved by using a newer version of cordova-ios plugin: 5.0.0