# INIntets bug? Response.: Property name must contain characters

Tags: xml, xcode, xcode11, siri, sirikit

I am messing around with SiriKit Intents and as part of that I am currently getting this error when trying to build:

`Response.: Property name must contain characters`

Never heard of it and all my Response and summary fields are definitely filled.

One thing I was trying out is to display the `Printed Dialog` with newLines, which at least isn't possible with the normal INIntentDefinitionEditor(-thing) so what I did is basically editing the intents xml a bit like this:

```xml
...
<key>INIntentResponse</key>
    <dict>
        <key>INIntentResponseCodes</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>INIntentResponseCodeConciseFormatString</key>
                <string>Hi,
Nice to meet ${you}.
Goodbye.</string>
                <key>INIntentResponseCodeConciseFormatStringID</key>
...
```

And I could see it working in the TextField in the IntentDefinitionEditor as well so I don't think that should be the reason or am I wrong and that actually broke it? .-.

EDIT: oh, and I do use those auto-complete 'symbols' (like `${you}`) and removing those didn't work either..

Any ideas welcome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after removing the intent and starting over (aka discarding all recent changes I made) it somehow just started working....

**Important:** It IS indeed possible to use multilines with SiriKit as responses like I did, that's not the issue. It's valid XML and works just fine...

My best guess is that it was just some bug similar to [this other SiriIntents bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241579/install-claimed-to-have-succeeded-but-application-could-not-be-found-on-device/57342370#comment101528072_57342370).
Other approaches are to clean the build folder, delete the "DerivedData" folder and re-build the project.

Good luck, y'all!