# Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0' - StickerPackExtension requires a development team error

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I am facing the below issue and am unable to build the application.

> XXX has conflicting provisioning settings. XXX is automatically
>   provisioned, but provisioning profile WildCard has been manually
>   specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the
>   build settings editor, or switch to manual provisioning in the target
>   editor. Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK
>   'iOS 10.0'

I am also unable to choose a particular profile.

[image]

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: have you installed iPhone Configuration Utility to manage provisioning profiles?

Comment: I have it installed but no idea how it's related to my question

Comment: do you any profiles there?

Comment: I see list of provisioning profiles in depricated one

Comment: try deleting them and re-install, restart Xcode, hopefully it works.

Comment: pls check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/40149920/1918002

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42338066/1084174 this may solve the problem

Comment: Related: [None of your accounts are a member, code signing errors after upgrading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39754341/55075)

Answer (score 752):

Holy molly, I had to do all this in order for it to work. A picture is worth a thousand words.

- If you get this error while archiving then continue reading.

  [image]
- Go to your app and click on the general tab. Under the signing section, uncheck "Automatically manage signing". As soon as you do that you will get a status of red error as shown below.

  [image]
- Now here's the tricky part. You need to uncheck "Automatically manage Signing" in both the targets under your project. This step is very important.

  [image]
- Now go under "build settings" tab of each of those targets and set "iOS Developer" under code signing identity. Do the same steps for your "PROJECT".

  [image]
- Now do Xcode → Product → Clean. Close your project in Xcode and reopen it again.
- After this go to the general tab of each of your targets and check "Automatically manage signing" and under team drop down select your developer account

  [image]
- Do an archive of your project again and everything should work.

Really, Apple? Was this supposed to make our lives easier?

Comment: If I'm being 100% - I don't really understand why this worked. But it did, and the pictures made a big difference. Thank you, wise wanderer.

Comment: I only had to uncheck and recheck the "Automatically manage signing". It then made me choose my team and had a popup confirming it was reseting some settings. Then it worked!

Comment: Don't forget to 'Close your project in Xcode and reopen it again'. This is important, at least to me :(

Comment: Don't scare if you don't have multiple targets. I didn't have any and the process worked like a charm. I wouldn't be able to realise of all this process, you are a genius!

Comment: I had problems with certificate. Revoke didn't help, but after the clean and restart the certificate showed up. Nice!

Comment: Your solution really helped. I was a bit confused with "uncheck Automatically manage Signing in both the targets." This could be due to Xcode 8.0 and the pictures not lining up. Thanks for taking the time to provide the solution +1

Comment: I've tried this, but still i cant upload my project with deployment provision profile.

Comment: You probably saved me hours of work. You should send an invoice to Apple for nonsense like this.

Comment: in my case `Automatically manage Signing` wasn't actually checked by default and checking it solved my problem!

Comment: Please can you clarify **precisely** what "Go to your app and click on the general tab" is.  My app features in numerous locations on the screen, there are boatloads of menus, tabs etc.  I just can't find what you have in your second screenshot or the mysterious "project editor" mentioned in the error message.

Comment: I actually got a warning when submitting app saying "potential loss of keychain access" as signing identity didn't match my previous version.  So I came across this post, and  I just turned off the auto provisioning following your steps and pointed to my known identities as I don't trust the automation and prefer the "old ways" as it selected some new identity that it must have autogenerated and does not even exist on my account!  Thanks for the tips!  It seems Apple consistently breaks something with the publishing process each version of XCode.

Comment: "Really apple? This was suppose to make our lives easier?"  Unbelievable, isn't it ?  We're almost in 2017, and Xcode still behaves like a spoilt child from the 1980s.  All that money, and they refuse to employ an Xcode developer with skills in actually making this stuff user-friendly.  It's a disgrace.

Comment: @Jeremiah is spot on. Unchecking, rechecking, and restarting Xcode worked. Face. Palm.

Comment: We had this issue in combination with a apple watch and the apple watch extension. Worked here as well with Xcode 8.2.1. It looks like `ProvisioningStyle = Automatic;` wasn't set at all this changed after i clicked through your instructions. Further the watchkitExtension Project had no Code Signing Identity for the entry "Any wachtOS SDK" there i hat to put iOS Developer in, no matter if on a Release or Debung Configuration

Comment: In addition to these steps I had to go to Product -> Scheme -> new scheme to get it to work.  Thanks

Comment: Unchecked and checked `Automatically manage signing` also **cannot** fix the  bug. I follow up your steps, then it's worked. Thanks.

Comment: This is cool stuff ! Works for the Appium Server automation tests. Just got a long pending Automation Server issue fixed at work !

Comment: I will never understand Apple Code signing. After years of doing this. smh, thank you.

Comment: Yes!  This works, although I did have to do a headstand for 5 seconds after I closed Xcode, and opening it up again.

Answer (score 68):

Great, now we can choose the profile for Debug and Release separately in the general tab itself as illustrated in the image below.

Also when you click on `Automatically manage signing` it does all process that are created by `Fix issue` in previous Xcode versions.

[image]

Comment: It makes all issues that 'Fix issue' used to create available automatically :(

Answer (score 62):

Disabling automatic and then re-enabling has solved this for me in Xcode 8 GM seed. This can be done in the project settings, info tab for each target that needs to be signed.

Comment: @aryaxt yea I hope my hours of pain can help other people not have hours of pain

Comment: This is a simple and great answer!!

Comment: Best answer  , normally I have to spend lots of time solving building issues

Comment: It's August 2017 with Xcode 8.3.3 this solution still works.

Comment: As a developer I feel awkward finding out that this solution actually worked for me. Bravo!

Answer (score 38):

I hate to say it. I just quit Xcode and opened it again. Simple and effective :)

Comment: All technique in IT. Quick and open again. Thanks! haha

Comment: I had to quit XCode as well. Quitting XCode is quickly becoming my standard debugging technique.

Comment: This is the closest answer. I had to use the menu File/Close Project, then Open Recently... this worked for me.

Comment: Unbelievable, but that's true.

Answer (score 21):

**For resovle this issue:**

1. Go to Xcode/Preferences/Accounts
2. Click on your apple id account;
3. Click - `"View Details"` (is open a new window with "signing identities" and "provisioning profiles";
4. Delete all certificates from `"Provisioning profiles"`, empty trash;
5. Delete your Apple-ID account;
6. Log in again with your apple id and build app!

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you...This worked for me and afterwords I just had to choose my team developer account.

Comment: Good tip... but frustrating that Xcode's upto v8.1, and we're still having to do dodgy workarounds like this.  Are they ever going to make it user-friendly ?

Answer (score 17):

This is what I would call a classically Apple Xcode UX design bug.

The error said there is a bunch of stuff YOU DID WRONG LOCALLY.

The error actually meant "*we have a new agreement you did not accept online*".

[image: After checking and unchecking the Automatic Signing button, I got this agreement error to display]

After checking and unchecking the Automatic Signing button I got this agreement error to display:

[image: Signing into the developer portal I was able to see a banner for the agreement update notice]

Signing into the developer portal I was able to see a banner for the agreement update notice:

[image: Restarting Xcode 8 then cleared that error and only forced me to reselect the certificate I already had on my machine and tied to the project].
Restarting Xcode 8 then cleared that error and only forced me to reselect the certificate I already had on my machine and tied to the project.

This could have been handled in a less confusing implementation, but this is how I fixed it. I am putting it here because it's way different than the steps everyone else gave.

Oh and yeah, having the pre-latest iOS 10 device and latest Xcode (I was on 7.3.1 or something) also threw errors until I updated.

Comment: Also happened when my membership expired.

Answer (score 15):

This is how it worked for me:

1. Kill Xcode and launch again
2. Open project again
3. Clean Project
4. Go to project settings > general > uncheck  'automatically managed profiles' and than 'check' again it will prompt for **enable**.
5. Now try archiving the source code

P.S Killing Xcode and launch again is the best thing to do if facing any random issue

Answer (score 11):

I fixed it doing this:

Set your team for all the targets of your project. Including the extensions. And left the automatic signing management.

[image: Code signing config]

Answer (score 9):

Steps:

1. Under *General* → *Signing*
2. Uncheck: **Automatically manage signing**
3. Select *Import Provisioning*

Comment: Umm and what should I import? This makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 7):

I only needed to uncheck 'Automatically manage signing', check it again, and rebuild.

Comment: This did it for me! Glad I searched *before* spending hours trying to fix.

Answer (score 7):

The Untick-tick (check-uncheck) *"Automatically manage signing"*.) of Xcode checkboxes don't work for me (as many suggested on the top).

It happens with frameworks linked in your project.

## Solution:

- Find your **framework** or any other target that required signing.
- Go to `Build settings`
- Search `Signing Identity`
- Set **Don't code sign** manually.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped me to solve my issue. Even there is no such option in my interface (xcode 12.3) but it started working when I was trying out your answer. I posted my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65739207/4428219

Answer (score 5):

Click on *Add Account* if not signed in.

Then after select your team profile and check *Automatically manage signing* and leave everything else as is in Xcode. It will perform the remaining stuff by itself.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this type error by updating the Xcode version to 8.0,
and under the `Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'`

There is a warning:

> isn't code signed but requires entitlements. It is not possible to add entitlements to a binary without signing it.

My solution is go to the *TARGET* → *General* → *Signing* -> click the  *Enable signing...* button, and I solved the issue.

Comment: The only solution that worked for me. Why is the suggested answer restarting?

Answer (score 4):

If you are finding the following screen and facing the problem of code signing required, then one of the following solutions may help you.

[image: Image_1]

**Solution 1**. As said before, sign in with an Apple ID. Then you will get options like this, if you enter correct bundle identifier. Then select the appropriate profile from the list.

[image: Image_2_after_adding_apple_id]

**Solution 2**. If you don't want to sign in with your Apple ID, then change a small flag in project.pbxproj file. Find the following text in the project file.

```
/* Begin PBXProject section */
```

Change flag `ProvisioningStyle = Automatic;` to `ProvisioningStyle = Manual;` Refer to the following image. After changing the flag, you will see the options to select appropriate profile from the list.

[image]

Comment: I tried doing this `ProvisioningStyle = Manual;`.
Unfortunately dd'nt help

Comment: @SupriyaKalghatgi, Which XCode version you are using ?

Comment: Option 2 worked for me, since I'm not able to sign into the dev account on Xcode.

Answer (score 4):

in `Build Setting` change in  `Signing`

[image]

`Clean` and `Archive` your code , Hope it will help you .

Answer (score 4):

Xcode Version 11.0:

I recently upgraded to Xcode Version 11.0.

Looks like Apple moved the Signing to a new tab from the original General tab.

1. Navigate to the application
2. Select "Signing & Capabilities"
3. Click "Enable Development Signing"

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Firstly in general tab -> signing section -> select a development team, manage signings

Similarly if you are working with multiple pod files select each pod target separately and go to general tab -> signing section -> select a development team, manage signings

repeat the same process for all pods in your project

Clean -> Build the project.

This worked for me

Comment: I was able to double click the project above the error in the left pane and the correct window appeared.

Answer (score 3):

In unit test target

Xcode 7:

- Must have provisioning profiles set (the same as in app target)
- Must have "don't sign" under certificates

Xcode 8:

- Must have 'None' set for provisioning profiles
- Must have certificates set (the same as in app target)
- (Must also have 'None' set for deprecated provisioning profiles)

Answer (score 3):

All answers looks fine but i found still issue so i changed settings in Build like this in XCode 9.0 - Sharing it so it could help someone.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After applying all the solutions above, The same issue I was getting. i.e
[image]

So I solved this by removing the provision profile in build sending.
Please find the images which will make you more clear

[image: My Signing details in build setting]

[image: I removed the provision profile]

Comment: i deleted them. But are you sure that this won't cause any problem

Comment: For me I did not face any problem. But for safe side just keep an copy of it.

Comment: I had the same error in the Signing Status section. I fixed it by removing PROVISIONING_PROFILE codes same you. After that the error in Signing section was gone. But I still cannot build my project with the same error: "Code signing is required ..."

Comment: @pyfyc after deleting provisioning profile clean the project and try again.

Comment: @kalpa I have tried that many times but it did not solve the problem. Maybe my case is a bit specific, I also described it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65713315/4428219. You can take a look if you want. In the meantime I will try other suggestions from this thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Even when installing the Watch OS application extension, the same error occured in Xcode 8.1:**

[image]

After updating the Provisioning Profile to Empty in Project of Build
Settings, everything work fine.

[image]

&& **Code Signing Identity** to **iOS Developer** in every targets Build Settings.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded to Xcode 8, and iOS 10, but I had the problem.

I fixed it by going to project general tab, signing section.

Click "Enable signing....."

That is it.

Answer (score 1):

If you get this error while compiling in Microsoft Mobile Center

> ❌  Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK
>   'iOS 10.3'
>
> ** ARCHIVE FAILED **

be aware that Mobile center doesn't yet support automatic signing with certificates of type app-store, ad-hoc and enterprise. Automatic signing only works with development certificates.

There are two things you can do to work around that limitation:

1. Use a development certificate. You'll have to create a new one in the developer.apple.com portal, download it to your machine, export it to a .p12 file using keychain, then finally provide it to Mobile Center. You know the drill.
2. Disable automatic signing. You will find that setting in Xcode in your project targets. Once disabled, a little "i" button will be displayed next to the "Xcode managed profile" label. Click that button, some info about the profile will be displayed. On the top left corner of that window, a "PROV" icon is displayed. That is the provisioning profile that you should provide to Mobile Center. Drag and drop the icon into the corresponding field in Mobile Center.

.  [image: Xcode]

Answer (score 1):

I did everything and didn't worked. I uninstalled Xcode 10 and installed Xcode 9.4 then it worked out of the box !

Answer (score 1):

If you still have problem then please try this.

> Build Settings -> User Defined -> Provisioning profile (Remove this.)

It will solved my issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have tried above all issue but was not working for me
What I tried is

First of all, I want to go with manual code signing process, I am not doing via automatic code signing

- I specify team name
  [image]
- Then change deployment target 
  [image]
- Clean and build

You will good to go now

Answer (score 0):

1.1: If you are using p12 and a provision file, but not using AppID to log in, do not Select **Automatically manage signing**.

Which means you don't need to set your team. Just select your provision file and the machine code signing identity in **Build Settings**, like this [Build Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsQCr.jpg). Make sure the parameters are set as well.

And then go back to **General**. You will see [General set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WizgA.jpg), and that's OK.

2. If 1 does not work, try as other answers said, **clean your project, delete the derived data folder, quit Xcode, and open again**.

Answer (score 0):

Just download your provisioning profile again from your developer account.
And sign out all developer accounts from Xcode → *Preferences* →  *Accounts* →  *Select Account showing at left and press -(subtract sign)

After deleting all accounts, press the <kbd>+</kbd> sign (add) button and sign in with all developer accounts.

It will work like a charm...

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have not choosen a team when you created the project.

I am such fixed. And I choose it in build settings, but invalid. I must create a new project.

[image]

"I choose it in build settings, but invalid. I must create a new project." is wrong.

It is invalid because I have not chosen it in extension. You must choose a profile at your project's all extension, and there is no need to create a new.

[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJYDx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

select your target and search for user-Defined section on build Settings,select provisioning profile and delete it

[image: Delete provisioning profile]

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded a demo app and had this issue. I've Xcode `Version 14.1` and what worked for me is:

1. Go to `Signing and Capabilities` tab and check on
   `Automatically manage signing`
2. modify the `Bundle Identifier`. In my case I appended my name to the existing bundle identifier

[image: Xcode settings]