# None of your accounts are a member, code signing errors after upgrading to Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to run some example projects from GitHub. After upgrading to Xcode 8, I see the same set of errors for multiple projects:

- `None of your accounts are a member of '...': An unexpected error
  occurred. Xcode cannot find a team matching '...'.`
- `No profiles for '...' were found:  Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching '...'.`
- `Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'`

[image]

I've tried the steps described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39498874/2901178, but it didn't work.

Comment: I've been having similar issues with my Apple Watch target. Try removing the derived data folder manually, then clean your project, and build again. Also, select your project, go to general, and select automatically manage code signing for all targets of your project.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you found any Extensions under **TARGETS**. You have to choose the development team for that too. Hope this helps you.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have all Identities created. 
Go to Xcode Settings - Accounts - Account Details - Click "Create" for every identity you need. The rest will be solved with "Automatically manage signing".

This is what that screen should look like.
[image: Xcode account details]

Comment: Also, you would need to do this when Apple developer account password is changed.  It would not be an issue immediately but if you attach a new device then it would try to connect Apple service and fail with the message above.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Maniganda's answer. If you are using CocoaPods, be sure that you have checked each target for the Pods project.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: In my case this was the problem +1

Comment: this is great. for ionic people this can cause problems due to the installation of push native plugin.

Answer (score 0):

1.Open Xcode->Preferences[will see preferences.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8RUQ.png)
2.Click on Locations.[will see Locations window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzUA9.png.)
3.delete the derived data folder in the given path of archives below.
4.Force quit xcode and open again.

Answer (score -1):

You should uncheck this:

[image]

Don't let xcode manage if your project don't include in you account.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could set ithere:

Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> Apple IDs -> Add your account

[image]

Comment: This was not my issue but checking this lead me to a "Could not sign in. Retry?" dialogue which ended up being the issue.