# Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I have updated my Xcode to Version 8.0 and Swift to Version 3 and now it's showing me this error:

```
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'.
```

Please help me resolve this.
 I checked this question [Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0' - StickerPackExtension requires a development team error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806538/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk-ios-10-0-stic) and its answers but it didn't help me.
 I tried unchecking "Automatically manage signing" and did everything exactly what the users answered there.
 It didn't help at all. The error is still there.

Comment: No, I tried doing that. Didn't help.

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39754341/none-of-your-accounts-are-a-member-code-signing-errors-after-upgrading-to-xcode/39764131#39764131

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652867/code-sign-error-in-macos-sierra-xcode-8-resource-fork-finder-information-or/39667628#39667628

Comment: r u using any pod project...