# An unexpected error occurred. Xcode cannot find a team matching '3864BNZ255'

Tags: ios, xcode8

I am working 3 months on my project. I was debugging the project suddenly xcode crashed. After that, it shows 3 errors when I want to build project. I tested a lot of solutions that are in S.O like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39568005/xcode-8-shows-error-that-provisioning-profile-doesnt-include-signing-certificat), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806538/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk-ios-10-0-stic/39498874#39498874), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39754341/none-of-your-accounts-are-a-member-code-signing-errors-after-upgrading-to-xcode). Even I deleted my project, reinstall Xcode but I have issues. I can download new projects and create new projects. However, this special project does not work. I do not want to run my app on devices. I only need to run on simulator. I am using **xcode 8.3.3**. What can I do to solve this problem?

[image]

**Update**

I do not have a team. I used before none or my own Apple ID

Comment: In project settings if ' automatic code signing' is on, uncheck it and try

Comment: @SivajeeBattina It did not work. I used this solution as mentioned in the links in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this steps:

1. Removing all `certificates` of my account from `keychain`
2. Removing all `provisioning profiles` from Xcode
3. Download `provisioning profiles` again via Xcode
4. Adding `certificates` again to the keychain.

Comment: I don't want to run on device. So I don't have provisioning profiles

Answer (score 0):

select project from **project navigator**. 
**go to build setting** and search for team. Assign developer team below.[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the error you have posted, it's very clear that the issue related to **Code Signing & Profiles**. If  `automatic code signing` in your project settings is on, then uncheck it and try. Remove all of your provisioning profiles & certficates and try to run if in case running on simulator. Download latest certificates and profiles and try to run if in case running on device.

Comment: I don't want to run on device. So I don't have provisioning profiles