# Developer Team IOS 10 Apache Cordova Build

Tags: ios, xcode, apache, cordova, ios10

I have the following problem when compiling a project in IOS 10. The project needs the Developer Team to compile correctly.

sudo cordova build ios --device

When you run the command, the following error:

[image]

In some forums JIRA official Apache Cordova, show the following solution:

> **issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11845**

I have not found a way to implement it properly to avoid this error. Build.xcconfig also attempt to modify the file, but I failed to fix the error.

If anyone has any ideas, I appreciate it very much.

Thank you.

Comment: please run your project with xcode and follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806538/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk-ios-10-0-stic

Comment: thanks for the recommendation. But since XCODE if I work. What I need is to run either from the terminal.

Comment: just do **cordova build ios** then open yorprojectname.xcodeproj file from your application's platform/ios folder it will open in xcode

Comment: since I already XCODE the project and working properly assigning the Developer Team. But what I need is from the terminal to assign the Developer Team as mentioned in the following link: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11845

Comment: Which version of cordova do you have ?

Comment: They haven't make a release with the commit fixing your issue. For the moment, it is only on master  branch of cordova-ios. So, it won't work

Comment: the latest version 6.3.1