# Xcode 8 console building: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

when i updated my Xcode to 8.0 and try to build my application with this command:

```
xcodebuild -workspace 11.xcworkspace -scheme 11 -configuration Release -sdk iphoneos clean build
```

I face the following error:

```
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'
```

When i download the fresh revision and put in in Xcode i see the following, and i should change by my hands the team after this i can build

[image]

But when i'm building it through Xcode->archive everything works like a charm.
How to fix it via building through console?!

I have added my account to Xcode, so manuals which i found didn't help me.

Comment: Have you selected the team in Targets->General

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806538/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk-ios-10-0-stic

Comment: Maybe  you can say me how to send this flags through console?