# Test react-native app on iPhone without an Apple Developer account

Tags: iphone, testing, react-native

I am developing an app in React Native. Beside simulators, I was required to test the app on real devices. As it is obvious, it is easy to test an app on Android devices, but I do not know how to test my app on an iPhone device. Is there any way to test the app on an iPhone without an Apple Developer account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you just run react native app as normal Swift/Objective C app, but you need xCode. Plugin your device, choose it in xCode from devices and press play. Here are the details:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-ios.html
You don't need apple developer account to test it on (I'm not sure) about 5 devices (please correct me). Then you need account on apple developer site and register all devices.

Comment: I tried it exactly, I am in the same network with my MAC and I selected my phone as target. But the build failed with error " 'Project' requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile for the "Debug" build configuration in the project editor.
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'"

Comment: But I looked for build confifuration and it is in 'Debug' mode.

Comment: Do you have checked in `General` `Automatically manage signing`? Or you can change `Deployment Target` to `9.3` or lower. Or check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806538/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk-ios-10-0-stic anyway it's not a thing with apple dev account

Comment: Can you use this strategy to allow other people (remotely) to install and test your app?