# AppCode can't run on simulator and device

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, carthage, appcode

I can't run my app from AppCode, I keep getting the same error on simulator and device. It runs perfectly on both from XCode though.

The error I get is the following:

`Note:Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'`

I'm on AppCode and XCode version:

- AppCode 2016.3.2
  Build #OC-163.12024.9, built on January 25, 2017
- XCode version: Version 8.2.1 (8C1002)

I have another project that runs fine in AppCode, same settings, same code signing etc. The difference is that it uses podfiles so I run the `Project.xcworkspace`.

This project uses Carthage so I just try to run the `Project.xcodeproj`in here. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was caused by having the wrong path for the location in `PROJECT_NAME.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata`

it worked when I set it to this:
`location = "self:"`

Comment: Does anyone know how to force Appcode to use "-project" instead "-workspace"?

Answer (score 0):

There are following possible reasons for such error:

> 1. Bundle Identifier: Check bundle identifier for both apps, it will be different. Each bundle identifier is required to be
>      integrated/registered in apple developer account with specific
>      certificate for development and/or production mode. You may not have
>      integrated bundle identifier of this app in your apple developer
>      account.
> 2. Wrong Location Path: wrong path for the location in PROJECT_TITLE.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata
>      
>    here set: **location = "self:"**

Comment: Thanks for your help! I added my bundle identifier to my AppID's, but it still doesn't run from AppCode. Am I missing a step? I am also wondering how this explains that the app does run from XCode but not from AppCode.

Comment: @Marijn, can you share your source code (project) if it does not have confidential information in it.

Comment: Sadly it does, so I cant :( But I can look up anything that might provide more information!

Comment: Here is similar issue and several answers also. Hope this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806538/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk-ios-10-0-stic

Comment: I think it's not similar since my project runs perfectly from XCode, my main issue is that it doesn't run in AppCode.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be resolved by disabling **"Automatic code signing"** in your Xcode projects General settings and setting code signing certificates explicitly for your apps Debug and Release targets in the Build settings tab.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it! Making a development profile specifically for this project and my device and setting that manually as the Provisioning profile for debug. But it still doesn't run from AppCode and does run from XCode.