# AppCode, no iOS simulator showing up

Tags: ios, xcode, ide, jetbrains-ide, appcode

I've downloaded AppCode for iOS development. For my personal project I've a bunch of simulator to chose from. But for a work project there is no simulator but only "Add Configuration" (image attached below)
[image: Add Configuration from AppCode image]

I've already tried a bunch of stuff like the ones mentioned here [AppCode can't run on simulator and device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42412067/appcode-cant-run-on-simulator-and-device) and here [AppCode found no simulators to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51276656/appcode-found-no-simulators-to-run) but none of them seems to work.

The project has unchecked "Automatically manage signing" duo to some work requirements.  Does anyone know how to run AppCode and this particular project in a simulator? Why this project has no simulator while my personal project has the whole list?

---

Edit:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppCode configurations are different from Xcode schemes. You'll need to add a configuration, selecting a target to run. (If you select an app target, "Run" will run your app. If you select a test target, "Run" will run your tests.)

Once you have a configuration with an iOS target, you'll be able to select one of the simulators.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm not able to add any configuration (see edits) or find any resources that teach me how to add a configuration for running iOS Simulator. In addition to that (as I mention in my question) I have a personal project that shows me all my iOS simulators without further configurations/editing. This project require a configuration and I was wondering why, and how to make this work.

Comment: @manubrio Are you on an M1 machine? I have a project with Intel-only dependencies and the Apple Silicon version of AppCode won't let me select any targets. But I was able to use an Intel version instead (though it's slower due to Rosetta translation).

Comment: I am! I've just removed AppCode and reinstalled the intel version! But still not able to chose a target or configure a proper "Configuration"... In my opinion I'm not able to run my project duo to target problems... But I can't find how to set a proper target (The project contains 2/3 target)... On the other side, even if my personal project has two target everything is working just fine. (P.s. I am able to run the project in Xcode Rosetta! Both of them)

Comment: I solved it with: right mouse button on xcworkspace => open with Appcode, instead of opening the whole project with File => Open.

Comment: @manubrio Great! Write that up as a self-answer for others.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was that I imported the whole project in AppCode instead of opening the xcworkspace with AppCode!