# Maximo Anywhere - Build ipa files failed "Automation signing is disabled"

Tags: xcode, maximo, maximo-anywhere

I'm try to build ipa files from Maximo Anywhere Project from build command.
When I'm run below command

> ./build.sh all-dist

I got this error :

> Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To
>   enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdate to xcodebuild.

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Xcode and Maximo Anywhere do you have? I believe you have a problem with your provisioning profiles on your Mac similar to this [Automatic signing is unable to resolve an issue with the "projectName" target's entitlements file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43972982/automatic-signing-is-unable-to-resolve-an-issue-with-the-projectname-targets).

Did you follow all the steps here? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSPJLC_7.5.2/com.ibm.si.mpl.doc_7.5.2/install/t_install_ios_dev_tools.html