# Automatic signing is unable to resolve an issue with the "myProject" target's entitlements

Tags: ios, xcode

I have this issue and I'm pretty sure I have done nothing

even try to make a completely new empty project but still failed to build it on a physical device.
[image]

[image]

any thought?

Comment: Hope this one helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43972982/automatic-signing-is-unable-to-resolve-an-issue-with-the-projectname-targets