# Xcode 11.2 -The specified item could not be found in the keychain

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, keychain, codesign

I am running macOS Catalina and Xcode 11.2.1. When I try to run the app with my iPhone as the target, I get the error below. The app works fine with the simulators but not with my iPhone. I have "*Automatically manage signing*' selected, a unique bundle identifier and selected myself as the team.[Xcode Signing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqjgx.png) I have attached a screenshot of my KeyChain Access.[Keychain Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3QMe.png) Any help is greatly appreciated!

Error Message

> CodeSign
>   /Users/brycejones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dzzcypcmdfslcvdpimxyyhdxovdh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Beefcake.app/Frameworks/App.framework
>   (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
>       cd /Users/brycejones/Documents/Jockstrap/ios
>       export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
>        Signing Identity:     "Apple Development: Bryce Jones (68332RMZFC)" Provisioning Profile: "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *"
>                         (feb0d63c-1b17-4d3e-9424-f7be3db0182a)
>
> /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign
>   F5E7B34F6D56955BD93D0C061C40E56B8B558315 --timestamp=none
>   --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,flags /Users/brycejones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dzzcypcmdfslcvdpimxyyhdxovdh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Beefcake.app/Frameworks/App.framework

Answer (score 0):

Something you can try when there's a signing issue in Xcode:

1. Signing out of the Apple ID in Xcode and signing back in.
2. Try to remove saved provision profiles: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46349585/6426085

Also in some cases, if you toggle any of the capabilities (like Push Access) on and off. Xcode will try to automatically repair the signing issues.

3. Also sometimes for me: when this happened open Xcode Settings->Account->Manage Certificates->Click the plus icon and request new certificates (notice that this might revoke your existing certificates!)

Also another thing you can try is: In the Keychain access, expand the certificate to reveal the key. Double click the key and click on the `Access Control` tab. Do you see Xcode there?

Please follow up if none of these works