# iOS - Xcode Automatically Manage Signing Not Work With Ionic 4 Cordova Project

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, app-store, ionic4

I have created a iOS app using ionic 4 with cordova and I have used following command to build iOS platform.

```
ionic cordova platform add ios@4.5.1

ionic cordova build ios --prod --release
```

After that I have open the xcodeworkspace file using Xcode and tested using simulator as well.

But when I trying to upload it to App Store I can't do it because this automatically manage signing doesn't work.

**Here is the error Xcode shows.**

`Xcode Version : 12.1`

[image: Xcode automatically manage signing error]

I have try following solutions but didn't work them.

1. Deleting provisioning profiles in ~/Library/MobileDevice/
2. Restart the Xcode
3. Adding and removing push notification capabilities as described here [iOS - automatic signing is unable to resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43972982/automatic-signing-is-unable-to-resolve-an-issue-with-the-projectname-targets)
4. All the solutions in here as well [Xcode - error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40824727/i-get-conflicting-provisioning-settings-error-when-i-try-to-archive-to-submit-an)
5. The file path is APP > Platforms > ios > Cordova > build-release.xconfig

And in the file, iPhone Distribution is explicitly set for CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY.

Change:

CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Distribution
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*] = iPhone Distribution
To:

CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Developer
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*] = iPhone Developer

After all these solution it shows above error.

**EDIT**
**I have a doubt with this signing certificate also. Is this normal with individual developer program ?**

[image: Signing certificate issue (a doubt)]

**EDIT 2**

**Here I have noticed identifiers are automatically created using Xcode. But there is no certificates or profiles. Why is that?**

[image: Only identifiers are added]

**EDIT 3**
**Manual signing works**

After suggestion by

> @MostafaHarb

I have add certificates and profiles manually add install them. After that only it allows me to use manual signing.

[image: Manual signing]

Comment: Did you create a profile for this app, and gave that profipe the right distribution certificate?

Comment: No. I want to create it automatically.

Comment: It sign it automatically, which means it will automatically find the profile package name with project package name, but you nead to create that profile first so that it detects it.

Comment: You mean identifiers? You can see my 2nd image in he question that identifier is creat automatically

Comment: I have trying creating certificates and profiles. But nothing happen. Same error. 

Comment: Under identifiers tab, there is profile tab, inside it create your new profile, inside it specify the identifier and the distribution certificate and give it a name like project name

Comment: After you create it, double click on it and it will be imported into your keychain for future use

Comment: I have do all these things @MostafaHarb

Comment: Only thing I can do is manual signing

Comment: What do you mean by it only allow manual signing... do you mean checkbox is disabled or what?

Comment: Checkbox is not disabled. I can enable it. But above error is still appearing. When I disable checkbox and using manual signing. Then it works fine.

Comment: To remove the error on signing, go to keychain , right click on login and put lock keychain and then right click and unlock keychain and test again, if it didn't work, in key chain click file and clear login then in xcode it will create the peofile automaticaly

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance. But I can't find a place to clear login. It has only delete login