# Ionic3 build iOS release version error "conflicting provisioning settings"

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I just purchased apple developer license, it is the first time for me to build a release version for iOS.

I try follow this article http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html

Everything in Apple website is fine, until the step to run `ionic cordova build ios --release` and reached error (attached at the end).

**Troubleshooting actions:**

I tried to open the project in xcode: go to signing -> untick "automatically manage signing" -> signing(release) -> select the team -> give "iOS Distribution" to Signing certificate -> run`ionic cordova build ios --release` in terminal, but still fails with the same error.

How do I fix this issue?

`xxx has conflicting provisioning settings. xxx is automatically signed for development, but a
        conflicting code signing identity iPhone Distribution has been manually specified. Set the code signing identity
        value to "iPhone Developer" in the build settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the project editor.
        Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.3'`

Comment: Let me know if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806538/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk-ios-10-0-stic

Comment: no, it didnt :(, this seems an issue for cordova/ionic. There could be extra steps to do.

Comment: I have the feeling this is something you have to tweak in XCode...

Comment: http://www.dpogue.ca/articles/cordova-xcode8.html https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/migrating_code_signing.html#signing-in-xcode-8

Comment: What does ionic info give you btw? Might be worth including that in your post

Comment: And what does "allow access to microphone” in ionic 3 have to do with the message you get from ionic cordova build ios --release? Is there a cordova plugin that you think is causing the problem?

Comment: @JGFMK Oops, thanks for telling me, the titile was incorrectly copy-pasted. I have updated the title. I now try to use FastLane tool to manage certificates, it works like a charm. Apple profile/certificate stuff is too confusing for first time users.

Comment: https://fastlane.tools/ ... interesting will take a look at that too...