# ARKit and Xcode 9 requiring a provisioning profile

Tags: deployment, macos-sierra, ios11, arkit, xcode9

I'm **brand new** to iOS development, Xcode, Swift, etc. I just upgraded to Mac 10.12.6 Sierra and downloaded the new Xcode 9. I just want to deploy a simple ARKit app to my iPhone for good hobby fun. I'm *not* a professional iOS developer writing some huge app for profit (TL;DR: I have no interest in spending $99 USD/yr for a developer license just so I can make fun little apps for my own private use!).

So I open Xcode 9 and create a new Augmented Reality project:

[image]

I then fill out project properties:

[image]

So it starts complaining that my project requires a development team:

[image]

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39498874/4009451), the solution is to uncheck the "*Automatically manage signing*" checkbox. So I do that, **but now I see a new set of errors:**

[image]

Searching for "xcode requires a provisioning profile" doesn't seem to kick up any helpful results. Any ideas what the fix is here?

#### Update

Per @rickster's suggestion I re-checked the "*Automatically manage signing*" checkbox, which then allowed me to select a *Team*. I selected my logged in account ("Personal Team"), and after a few seconds a *new* error has appeared:

[image]

> "*Failed to create provisioning profile.*"

**Any idea as to why this is failing and what the fix is?**

Comment: Nobody on SO develops iOS apps? Nobody knows how to provision a profile for Xcode 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to plug your phone into your computer and keep the phone from locking. Then go back to the main `General` tab in your project and Xcode should automatically create the provisioning profile for you. HTH!

Comment: Hey that worked! Thanks so much (+1, check & bounty)!

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing specific to ARKit here — building and running any app on an actual device requires signing.

However, if you have an Apple ID (like you use for iCloud, iTunes purchases, Apple Music membership, etc) you can develop on your own device — just sign into that account in Xcode > Preferences > Accounts. You can't deploy to the App Store or even ad hoc distribution that way, but it's good for getting started. Once you're further along you can join a [developer program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/) for deployment and resources.

Comment: Thanks @rickster (+1) - so I signed in to my Apple ID account (like you said, via `Xcode >> Preferences >> Accounts`, but still the  last screenshot above remains (it's still requiring a provisioning profile). Is there another step I need to take here? Thanks again!

Comment: @smeeb it should allow you to select a "Team", you need to select your AppleID ("Personal Team") and then Xcode should take care of the rest

Comment: Thanks so much @orangenkopf (+1) - please see my 4th/last screenshot above...where on that screen can I select a *Team*? There's both a `Signing (Debug)` as well as a `Signing (Release)` accordion pane, and both panes have a `Team` label field with a value of `None`...but they don't allow me to actually *select* a `Team`...any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: When you’re logged into an account, the “automatically manage signing” box should be checked.

Comment: Thanks @rickster (+1) please see my update above, if you don't mind...once I re-check that checkbox, I get a new error "Failed to create a provisioning profile", any ideas why this would be failing?

Answer (score 0):

just add quotes between the name bundle identifier!

ex:
"io.ionic.starter"
or
-io.ionic.starter-

Good work for you !