# #audiokit examples broken? framework not found error, code signing error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, audiokit

I’m new to working with Frameworks, #AudioKit in particular, and I'm stuck at the very beginning of tutorials & examples. They seem to require a lot of extra setup that is not explained/included in the documentation or tutorials.

I *think* I have successfully installed and done all the basic framework setup (correctly installed AudioKit, Carthage, and CocoaPods), and that the issues I'm having are related to running older projects in newer versions of Xcode, but I'm not 100% sure.

**1.) Missing Framework Error**

I'm getting this error a lot:

> ld: framework not found Pods_[NameOfProject] clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

For example, In the basic AudioKit tutorial (https://www.raywenderlich.com/145770/audiokit-tutorial-getting-started1), I get

> ld: framework not found Pods_[NameOfProject] clang: error: linker

How do I find/build this missing project-specific framework? And, more importantly, how should I troubleshoot this? Did I miss a step in the installation?

On this example, the project is dead, the file is unusable, and discussion on the tutorial page is closed. :confused:

I see that my project folder has Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-AudioKitPlaygrounds/ but it is missing this extra framework.

(Another example: SenderSynth (./AudioKit-iOS/Examples/), from the AudioKit example files, is missing **Pods_SenderSynth.framework**, with the same error.)

**Solutions attempted:**

I have searched this error and for this framework in StackOverflow, and on the interwebs, but the answers I've found are either unclear, do not apply, or do not work.

On the AudioKitPlaygrounds tutorial, I tried converting to current Swift syntax, and this caused Xcode to crash.

I tried building a Cartfile in the project (including linking and running the appropriate scripts). When that failed, I tried building a Podfile to include the framework (also including the link & script). I’m still confused about when/whether to use Cartfile vs CocoaPods – the tutorials all seem to require some extra setup before use that is not included in the tutorial, and the AudioKit site is missing any cohesive setup instruction for a noob like me. (Have I missed an installation step?)

**2.) Code signing error**

Next question, possibly related: On many of the example projects I get the error "Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.1'"

If I select my developer profile under "Team" I get "Failed to create provisioning profile."

I have encountered this error before, and it seems to just appear in random cases, fix sometimes and sometimes not (depending on the project).

**Solutions attempted:**

I tried this solution: [Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0' - StickerPackExtension requires a development team error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806538/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk-ios-10-0-stic) , but it does not help (i.e. I get the same result/errors).

**Questions**

- If I'm downloading some old tutorial project from the interwebs, will I always need to rebuild the framework (e.g. using Carthage or CocoaPods, adding the links & run scripts)? (Or did I miss an installation step?)
- If so, how do I know which **version** of a framework to use? Is this info embedded somewhere into the project?
- Is it important which **framework manager** was used to create the project? What clues should I look for?

Of course, all these issues seem to vanish when building my own projects from scratch.

Any guidance is appreciated.

**aTdHvAaNnKcSe**
(THANKS in advance)

Comment: When you install with cocoa pods, did you remember to close the project, then open the xcworkspace?

Comment: I can do a screenshare if you want.  Screenhero is dead, but possible TeamViewer or some other service.

Comment: @aureliusprochazka that would be greatly appreciated - thank you! My schedule is a bit hectic thru the weekend. Would anytime on Monday work (day or night)? That would also give me time to set up TeamViewer or some such....

Comment: @dave234 yes I did. I seem to be getting the same error whether or not I install a Podfile. (I guess this indicates the original project was created using cocoaPods, but somehow the Podfile and .xcworkspace disappeared?)

Comment: Hi did you solve your issue? It seems now the issues are still there.