# Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.3 when build using VSTS

Tags: ios, iphone, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, auto-build

[image]
i tried to make build using VSTS but get failed build because code signing required, although switch to Manual signing and fill  Signing identity = $(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)
Provisioning profile UUID = $(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)
and same error

Comment: Can you build successful on your own mac book manually? If you meet the same error on your local machine, you can refer this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806538/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk-ios-10-0-stic/39379587). And if you can build succeed on your local machine, can you provider detail build logs? And what's your project type? And do you develop on xcode or VS? etc.

Comment: yes i can build success in my macBook, what you need to know from build log? what you type of project ? i develop on Xcode

Comment: For asking the detail build logs (set system.debug variable as true), it helps us to debug the problem more clearly. And for the project type, is it ios application, framework or mac os x application etc?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I had `Manual Signing` enabled and also had the `Export Options` set to `Specified` (with  `TeamID` and ​`Export Method` set).

I changed the `Export Options` to `Automatic` and the task was able to select what was defined in the provision profile I have installed earlier (via a task).

-S