# Having issue in React Native app running on IOS device

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am running my react native app on IOS but it is not working it is showing an error:

```
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 13.0'

No profiles for 'org.reactjs.native.example.app' were found:  Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'org.reactjs.native.example.app'.

Failed to register bundle identifier. The app identifier "org.reactjs.native.example.app" cannot be registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont have a developer team associated with your target , or you must have used a duplicate bundle identifier.
Your bundle identifier is already in use by other developers I guess, so just change your bundle identifier in the Identify tab right above your Signing tab to another one:
For eg: Bundle Identifier: com.xyz.abc

And you can view this in the signing and capabilities tab after you selected your target in xcode
[image: Xcode image]

After that it should work, otherwise tell me the error, ill solve it

Comment: I have added team already it is working on simulator but on when running on actual device it is showing these errors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806538/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk-ios-10-0-stic