# Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 14.3'

Tags: ios, xcode12

I am trying to build an old iOS application in xcode 12.3 (macOS Catalina 10.15.6). The app was written by another person many years ago. So previously it was signed by another AppleID certificate.

Now I have already managed to build the app in xcode 12.3 and I can successfully run it on a virtual device (iPhone 11 pro). However when I try to run the app on the real iPad (iOS version 14.2) connected via usb I am getting this error: "Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 14.3'".

I have already searched in SO and found few threads from many years ago which are not really helpful for me.

What have I tried so far?

1. Enabled two-step authentication for my AppleID and added my AppleID to xcode.
2. In project -> Signing and Capabilities section I enabled Automatic Signing and selected my Team (which is shown as 'FirstName LastName (Personal Team)'). Everything looks OK now in Signing and Capabilities section, no errors.
3. I have also tried to create a test app and I was able to run it on the same iPad connected to my comp. I used the same my AppleID that I am using with my real project.

Before the error there is also warning: ""MyProject" isn't code signed but requires entitlements. It is not possible to add entitlements to a binary without signing it."

Comment: Did you change the bundle ID (The existing bundle ID will be associated with whichever developer account initially create the app)?  Do you have a paid developer membership?  Some entitlements (such as IAP) are not available to free accounts

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes. I did change the bundle Id for a new unique one. I do not have paid developer membership. How to see what entitlements are used in my project?

Comment: @Paulw11 I think I found it. If you click on the small 'i' icon to the right of the Provisioning Profile string it shows popup window where I found: Entitlements 4 included: Includes application-identifier, keychain-access-groups, get-task-allow, and com.apple.developer.team-identifier.

Answer (score -1):

Somehow I managed to run my app on external device (iPad) finally. I don't really understand how I did it but at some point it just compiled without errors and then started.

I was just trying out every suggestion one after another from this thread: [Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0' - StickerPackExtension requires a development team error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37806538/4428219). I set up Automatic Signing with my AppleID, selected my Team, changed BundleID, changed Deployment Target version to 14.2 (the same as in my iPad), etc. I also tried to Clean the project and restart xcode after every change - nothing worked for me. But suddenly it started working after I changed Code Sign Identity under Build Settings for both targets (main app and tests). I just changed Code Sign Identity back and forth and it start working. Finally I set Code Sign Identity to "Apple Development" (as it was suggested in the error message in Signing tab).

It is funny but the answer that I was trying out at that time suggested totally different thing. But that answer was from few years back and there was no such settings in my interface. So I tried to set it in another way. And that is how it worked out for me. BTW, this is that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47664721/4428219.

Maybe later I will make more detailed research what exactly was the setting that made it work for me. But for now I just committed my working configuration and want to write it down here while I remember the sequence of events.